# Can I Configure Enterprise Manager Cloud Control on Standard Edition

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, windows-server, oracle-enterprise-manager, standard-edition

- Is it possible to configure enterprise manager cloud control on Oracle 12c Standard edition?
- Will it administer multiple databases (Non-CDB)?
- What about administering databases on different servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Is it possible to configure enterprise manager cloud control on Oracle 12c Standard edition?

[Infrastructure Repository Databases](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E55822_01/DBLIC/editions.htm#BABDFJIC)

> The infrastructure repositories for RMAN, Oracle Enterprise Manager
>   Cloud Control, AWR Warehouse, and Global Data Services Catalog can be
>   shared in one database, or deployed in separate databases. **Enterprise
>   Edition must be used** for the infrastructure repository database(s).

- Will it administer multiple databases (Non-CDB)?

Yes, that is the point of a central monitoring environment.

- What about administering databases on different servers?

Yes, same as above.

Comment: As expected, I will have to move to Enterprise Edition.

Comment: Previously I remember that I have used Enterprise Manager Express, was't that bad. But for sure the cloud version has massive capabilities.